# Build a installable python package with C++

Tags: python, c++, package

I want to build a Python module that use C++ because it is much faster. I found out that I can use `subprocess` module to run an executable file however I can't build a package. I also tried `ctypes` but I can't return object like `std::vector` in C++. So what is the most efficient way to build a package with wrapped C++ code?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/basics.html) is the easiest way to build a C/C++ extension for Python.

Answer (score 1):

You should build a C/C++ Python extension module. See:

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html